# I want to make a sidebar with submenu. i try it but i face some error

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, navbar

I select the label using the `getElementsByClassName` and also select the drop-down using `getElementsByClassName` and I add a click event listener on the label which adds the hide class in the dropdown but it's not working, plz help.

this is the html code :-

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="label">
    <span>Profile</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Dropdown</li>
    <li>Dropdown2</li>
    <li>Dropdown3</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="#" class="label">
    <span>Profile</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Dropdown</li>
    <li>Dropdown2</li>
    <li>Dropdown3</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="#" class="label">
    <span>Profile</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Dropdown</li>
    <li>Dropdown2</li>
    <li>Dropdown3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

```
const Nav = document.getElementsByClassName("label");
const NavUl = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");

  Nav.addEventListener("click", function () {
    NavUl.classList.toggle("dpNon");
  });
```

I want to add display non `dpNon` classs with the `dropdown-menu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired result you will need to select all elements like before with `document.getElementsByClassName("label")`. Then loop the result, attach an event listener and then find the dropdown menu. Then you could toggle the class.

```js
const nav = document.getElementsByClassName("label");

Array.from(nav).forEach(element => {
   element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      //Find dropdown-menu from parent
      e.preventDefault();
      const target = element.parentNode.querySelector(".dropdown-menu");
      //
      if (!target) {
         return;
      }
      
      //Find openmenu
      const openMenu = target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".dpNon");
      //deactivate openMenu if openMenu is not the target 
      if (openMenu && openMenu !== target) {
        openMenu.classList.remove("dpNon")
      }
      
      //toggle class
      target.classList.toggle("dpNon");
   })
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu.dpNon{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#" class="label">
    <span>Profile</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Dropdown</li>
    <li>Dropdown2</li>
    <li>Dropdown3</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="#" class="label">
    <span>Profile</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Dropdown</li>
    <li>Dropdown2</li>
    <li>Dropdown3</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="#" class="label">
    <span>Profile</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Dropdown</li>
    <li>Dropdown2</li>
    <li>Dropdown3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: can we do this by using queryselector

Comment: and its only work for first element not for all

Comment: Do you want it to work for elements? Add the HTML So I can understand.

Comment: Is the HTML like .navName parent of .navUl, or are they sibling elements?

Comment: I edit my question and add the HTML

Comment: I have updated the code to match your desired output. If this helped mark the question as answered. Thanks

Comment: thx dear for your help

Comment: can you also explain how to close the dropdown when click the other or next dropdown